# Hive change table location for all partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, partitioning

After moving my table's data to `/some_loc`, I am able to change its location with a command such as:

`ALTER TABLE db.my_table SET LOCATION '/some_loc';` followed by

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE db.my_table;`

However, while this does move the table's location, the table is empty. When I do `show partitions db.my_table;` I see the partitions, but the are referencing the old location. I have to drop and recreate the table for the data to show up.

Is there a way make sure the partitions are pointing to the correct location when I change the location of the table?